# PyCharm not happy with `range()`

Tags: python-3.x, range, pycharm

I'm very new to PyCharm, or indeed any Python IDE, but I've been using Python for a while. When I use `range(1, 20)` in PyCharm for example, PyCharm would highlight the '20' and say "Unexpected argument". Why does PyCharm not expect the second argument and what can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

When I press `ctrl+B` on `range`, it takes me to the following source code.

```
def __init__(self, stop): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    pass
```

This resides in `class range(object)`.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. Could be a bug in Pycharm

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10163 ??

Comment: PyCharm 3.0 seems to have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with pycharm 2.7.3 if you update it will probably be fixed, i had pycharm older versions but i cant remember such bug. Could it possibly be that you import another range function that takes 1 arguement and it gets confused? what version do you use by the way?

Comment: exactly the same versions with me, but it works fine for me. do you use any import * by any chance? or can you ctr+click in the function to go in the source code? i suspect the ide "thinks" you use a different range function. When you ctrl+click on range it should go in builtins.py

Comment: When I press `ctrl+B` on `range`, it takes me to the following source code.

`def __init__(self, stop): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__`
    `pass`

Comment: strange i get the same. is that in builtins.py?

Comment: Yep that's in `builtins.py`. Also, I never use things like `import *`. Any idea?

Comment: very strange i have the same versions, it goes on the same file, it should give the same result

Comment: so builtins.py is saved in homedir/.PyCharm20/system/python_stubs/xxxxxxxxx/builtins.py try change def __init__(self, stop) to def __init__(self, stop, step=1): in that file. i bilieve it will do the trick. let me know if it worked or not, maybe we have to fire a bug in pycharm too. strange because it works for me.

Comment: in python doc: 
range(stop)
range(start, stop[, step])
pycharm seems to be confused because of that
( [link]http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range )

Comment: just something may be irrelevant v3.0 is out. maybe the new version is not broken :) http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/